# Access JQuery UI Widget from within Click callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My JQuery-UI widget should append a div to itself when clicked. But my button callback doesn't have access to `this.element` - it's undefined because I assume `this` refers to the button and not my widget. Please see the simple code below for a better description:

```
(function ($) {

  $.widget( "my.myWidget", {

        _create: function () {

            this.element.click(this.addRow);
        },

        addRow: function(evt) {

            // this.element is undefined?
            console.log("Is this.element defined: " + this.element != undefined);

            // cant append to this.element
            $('<div></div>')
                .appendTo(this.element);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

How can I access the widget (`this.element`) inside my click callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because the `this.element.click` listener callback is called from within a different scope. Therefore the scope from within the `addRow` is not the widget.

There are two ways of solving this problem.

Option 1: By storing `this` in a variable, so you can access it from within another scope. For example:

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget( "my.myWidget", {

        _create: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.element.click(function() {
                self.addRow();
            });
        },

        addRow: function(evt) {

            // this.element is undefined?
            console.log("Is this.element defined: " + this.element != undefined);

            // cant append to this.element
            $('<div></div>')
                    .appendTo(this.element);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Option 2: By binding the `this` scope to the `this.addRow` function object:

```
(function ($) {

    $.widget( "my.myWidget", {

        _create: function () {
            this.element.click(this.addRow.bind(this));
        },

        addRow: function(evt) {

            // this.element is undefined?
            console.log("Is this.element defined: " + this.element != undefined);

            // cant append to this.element
            $('<div></div>')
                    .appendTo(this.element);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare another object of this to use it within callbacks:

```
var _this = this;
```

define this at first line of you widget class.

Comment: can you elaborate where exactly? Should it be above `_create: ...` because that gives a compiler error (because its in a map/object). Where exactly?